# How to use Array Modifier on a segment of Bezier curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I would like to use the *Array Modifier* to array a mesh along a segment of a Bezier curve. However, based on my experience the *Array Modifier* gets applied to an entire curve, not a segment.

Is there a way to use the *Array Modifier* on just a portion of a Bezier curve?

Here is an example where spheres are arrayed along a Bezier curve. I am interested in arraying them along a portion of the curve (e.g. the first half of the curve).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of course, I'm not sure what you mean when you say that it gets applied to an entire curve, could you please show an example?

Comment: Sure thing. I added images of an example.

Comment: in the modifier, choose Fixed Count instead of Fit Curve

Comment: Nice, that works although the array starts at the start of the curve. Is there a way to have the array begin at some other position along the curve? For example, is there a way to have the array start at the midpoint along the length of the curve?

Comment: You can change the position of the object by moving the object for example. What is your final goal?

Comment: That makes sense. The goal is to make a race track. It's simple to have the track be uniform throughout. But, I'd like to vary the array elements along the track. For example, some parts of the track will have walls, other parts will have no walls, other parts will have a tunnel, etc.